# Excluding lombok from pom.xml in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml

I use lombok in my project and I realized the following `<exclude>` part in my pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            </exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I just add the lombok dependency and did not add this block. Is this something that lombok is also available and when I add it explicitly, it is excluded by adding this block automatically to the pom.xml?

If it is the case, should I use this approach (adding `<excludes>` block for the related library) when I use a different version for transitive dependencies e.g. `snakeyaml` ? Or should I just add the properties as shown below and override the transitive dependency version?

```
<properties>
    <snakeyaml.version>1.33</snakeyaml.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: As stated in the other question no you don't need to exclude it! The exclude in the plugin section is a totally different one then the one from the dependencies section! It is needed here because lombok is a provided dependency, by default those aren't included. However with a Spring BOot application those are included in the fat-jar. For lombok that isn't needed hence the exclude in the plugin section as to not include it in the resulting jar.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for reply. **1.** Do you mean that in order to remove a transitive dependency (for example when adding Lombok separately and it is also included in Spring), I just need to specify the version that I added in the `<properties>` tags as shown above, right?

Comment: **2.** In this scene, do I need to remove `<exclude>` part only or all the `<plugin>` part for `lombok` (shown above) above from pom.xml?

Comment: I strongly suggest you first start to learn how maven works. As you are mixing a lot of, unrelated, things together. 1. No, 2 No. Read my comment again.

Comment: Which one is unrelated? Did not you suggest to me that defining version using <properties> tag instead of excluding the transitive reference?

Comment: That is what I suggested and you should do, hence I don't get the gist of this question as that is more or less asking the same. The exclude you mention is for dependencies, the exclude here is for something entirely different. That are different beast. You also need to exclude it for a totally different reason.

Comment: Yes, I followed your suggestion. But I think excluding snakeyaml or lombox fom Spring when adding them as dependencies are the same, what is the difference? If you clarify us, there will be no confusion. After that I can also read, but at first it seems to be useful to clarify some points you mentioned.

Comment: No they aren't the same not even close. And as mentioned twice before en exclude in the dependencies section is different then the exclude here for the spring-boot-maven-plugin as I already explained in my first comment.

Comment: I think the problem with your explanations is not posting an example code and generally try to explain by words. But even if they are generally useful, unexperienced developers cannot get benefit from those unless you provide an example code. Instead of posting several comments, I think you would give an example part of pom.xml and show clearly the difference :)

Comment: @M.Deinum I agree with the OP that an answer with example configurations and explanation would be more useful than these comments.